# similar assert statements giving different results

Tags: c++, assert, comma-operator

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    char c,d;
    cin>>c>>d;
    assert ((a==b,a*b==9,c==d));
    assert ( a==b && a*b==9 && c==d );
}
```

If you :

1. input different integers or different characters, the first assert statement aborts the program. (as it should).
2. But , if you input equal integers (other than 3) and same characters in this code, the first assert statement doesn't abort the program, however the second assert statement does.

Is the first assert statement weak or is there something I not know about assert statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a==b,a*b==9,c==d` is comma expression. For [built-in comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator):

> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its
>   result is [discarded](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Discarded-value_expressions) (although if it has class type, it won't be
>   destroyed [until the end of the containing full expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime)), and its
>   side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression `E2`
>   begins
>
> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma
>   expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the
>   second operand, `E2`.

It returns the last operand as its return value, i.e. `c==d`. `a==b` and `a*b==9` get evaluated but their results are discarded. So `assert ((a==b,a*b==9,c==d));` only checks `c==d` in fact.

On the other hand `assert ( a==b && a*b==9 && c==d );` checks all the conditions; which are connected via `&&` then must all be `true` to pass the check.

Answer (score 1):

> > *1. input different integers or different characters, the first assert statement aborts the program. (as it should).*

The meaning of the comma operator in the general expression

```
e1 , e2
```

is - evaluate the subexpression `e1`, then evaluate `e2`; the value of the expression is the value of `e2`.

So, the value of expression

```
a==b,a*b==9,c==d
```

is value of

```
c==d
```

When you use this expression in `assert()`, if `c==d` results in `false`, regardless of value of `a` and `b`, the `assert()` results in program termination.

> > *2. But , if you input equal integers (other than 3) and same characters in this code, the first assert statement doesn't abort the program, however the second assert statement does.*

Logical AND operation `expr1 && expr2` employs short-circuiting behavior. With logical short-circuiting, the second operand, `expr2`, is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand, `expr1`.
That is, `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `0` (false).

In the expression given in second `assert()`

```
a==b && a*b==9 && c==d
```

you have `a*b==9` along with `a==b` and `c==d`. So, this expression result in `true` only when given input `3` to `a` and `b` and same character value input to `c` and `d` otherwise this expression result in `false` and the assert results in program termination.